# OpenID connect is not returning EMail id, Address and Phone number from Salesforce

Tags: open-id-connect

I am working on the Implementation of Salesforce as an identity provider using OpenId Connect authentication method.

I am using Auth0 to test this. I have mentioned Scope in Auth0 - **id openid profile email phone address**.

I have enabled **Include Standard Claims** in Salesforce. The Basic Flow is working and i could get several fields returned from User profile. However i am unable to fetch **EMail ID, Address, Phone, Role** fields. Pls find the attached screen shot

I need some help with regarding this issue.

The Basic [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Salesforce side in the connected app ([docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create_openid_connect.htm&type=5)):

- `openid` is the only scope needed under *Selected OAuth scopes*
- Select *Configure ID Token* and check *Include Standard Claims*

On the client side (Auth0), don't request any scopes. You can test with https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com as the client. When I do this, I get standard claims in the ID token:

```js
{
     "address": {"country": "US"},
     "at_hash": "...",
     "aud": "...",
     "email": "foo@bar.com",
     "email_verified": true,
     "exp": 1583450469,
     "family_name": "Staff",
     "given_name": "Identigral",
     "iat": 1583450349,
     "iss": "https://login.salesforce.com",
     "locale": "en_US",
     "name": "Identigral Staff",
     "nickname": "...",
     "phone_number": null,
     "picture": "...",
     "preferred_username": "...",
     "profile": "...",
     "sub": "...",
     "updated_at": "2019-10-24T16:48:51Z",
     "zoneinfo": "America/Los_Angeles"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked for me.